# Conditional Page Break on Excel range

Tags: excel, vba, page-break

Hopefully this qualifies as a programming issue given I don't think I can achieve this without VBA.

I have an Excel 2016 range, fixed in size and contents (x amount of rows), but given there's an expanding table above, moves up and down. It's essentially a signature right at the end.

I want to avoid splitting the printout of this range over two pages, hence need to add a page break before this specific range in case a part of it spills over to page 2 - and then to be fully printed on page 2, not just part of the range as it happens by default. Also, no need for this page break unless it all fits on page 1.

I do have a working code which I could enhance a bit to manually add page break in front of a range, but that would need this to be launched manually whenever the user sees a range partly spilling over to the next page - perhaps it's possible to automate this?

Any ideas on the possible approach?

```
Sub Page_break()

    Dim CellRange As Range
    Dim TestCell As Range

    ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks

    Set CellRange = Selection
    For Each TestCell In CellRange
        If TestCell.Value <> TestCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows(TestCell.Row).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
        End If
    Next TestCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Following idea:

1. Define a range that you want to keep together `RangeToKeep`
2. Loop through all horizontal page breaks
3. Check if one of these page breaks intersects with the `RangeToKeep`, if so insert a page break above.

Example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub KeepRangeTogether()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'define worksheet

    Dim RangeToKeep As Range
    Set RangeToKeep = Ws.Range("A23:A37") 'define range you wish to keep together

    Ws.ResetAllPageBreaks 'remove all manual page breaks 
                          '(only needed if this code is run multiple times on the same sheet)

    Dim pb As HPageBreak
    For Each pb In Ws.HPageBreaks 'loop through all page breaks
        If Not Intersect(pb.Location, RangeToKeep) Is Nothing Then 'if a page break intersects your RangeToKeep
            RangeToKeep.EntireRow.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual 'insert manual page break
            Exit For
        End If
    Next pb
End Sub
```